# Android - Find out if user used a pre-configured google account on Device or configured a new one

Tags: android, oauth, google-signin

I am using Google Sign-In in my Android app.

Now, when the `Account Chooser` opens up, Google provides user with 2 options: use an account you have already configured with the account, or add a new account.

How, dueto some requirements, I need to find out if the user added the new account from the `Account Chooser` while Signing In.

How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Iterate google accounts before and compare it to choosen one

Comment: how can I find the pre-configured accounts before login then?

Comment: With AccountManager

Comment: thanks! I'll look into it